# Java Decryption problems using chiper update\update\doFinal

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to write a function which encrypts\decrypts files using only cipher object, that is CipherInputStream are disallowed (homework problem). However after quite some time debugging I can't wrap my head around what's wrong.

Encryption works as far as I can tell (encrypting using open-ssl and comparing sha1sums of my code and open-ssl output, but decryption works only for the first 16 bytes then gives wrong data leading to BadPaddingException at the ending.

Code is divided into two function and one caller from main:

```
private static void symetricKeyCriptographyHandler(final int opmode, final Path source,
        final Path destination) {
    try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(source),
            BUFFER_BLOCK_SIZE);

            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(destination),
                    BUFFER_BLOCK_SIZE);

            BufferedReader scr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        System.out
        .format("Please provide password as hex-encoded text (16 bytes, i.e. 32 hex-digits):%n> ");
        byte[] key = hexToByte(scr.readLine().trim());
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        System.out
        .format("Please provide initialization vector as hex-encoded text (32 hex-digits):%n> ");
        byte[] iv = hexToByte(scr.readLine().trim());
        IvParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        // Writing out key and iv as debugging tools. Checks out as far as I can tell.
        for (byte b : key) {
            System.out.format("%02x", b);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (byte b : iv) {
            System.out.format("%02x", b);
        }
        System.out.println();

        cipher.init(opmode, keySpec, paramSpec);
        processCryptedData(cipher, in, out);
        System.out.format("%s completed. Generated file %s based on file %s",
                opmode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE ? "Encryption" : "Decription",
                        destination.getFileName(), source.getFileName());

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // Should never happen!!!
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFileException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getFile() + " does not exist.");
    } catch (AccessDeniedException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getFile() + " access is denied.");
    } catch (IOException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | ShortBufferException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException
            | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Helper function which takes cipher and input\output stream to do its job:

```
private static void processCryptedData(final Cipher cipher, final InputStream source,
        final OutputStream destination) throws IOException, ShortBufferException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    final int cipherBlockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
    // BUFFER_BLOCK_SIZE = 4096, chosen arbitrarily.
    // I'm aware it isn't used in the fullest. 
    byte[] buff = new byte[BUFFER_BLOCK_SIZE];
    int r;

    while ((r = source.read(buff, 0, cipherBlockSize)) > 0) {
        r = cipher.update(buff, 0, r, buff);
        destination.write(buff, 0, r);
    }
    destination.write(cipher.doFinal());
}
```

And finally caller from main:

```
        case "encrypt":
            if (args.length != 3) {
                System.err.println("Invalid number of command line arguments.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            symetricKeyCriptographyHandler(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Paths.get(args[1]),
                    Paths.get(args[2]));
            break;
        case "decrypt":
            if (args.length != 3) {
                System.err.println("Invalid number of command line arguments.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            symetricKeyCriptographyHandler(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Paths.get(args[1]),
                    Paths.get(args[2]));
```

EDIT (Thanks to @owlstead ):
Apparently using separate input\output buffer fixes the problems, though I'm confused since in Cipher documentation is noted that .update should be copy safe. 
The following code as far as I've tested works fine in processCryptedData:

```
    byte[] ibuff = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(BUFFER_BLOCK_SIZE)];
    byte[] obuff = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(BUFFER_BLOCK_SIZE)];
    int r;
    while ((r = source.read(ibuff, 0, BUFFER_BLOCK_SIZE)) > 0) {
        r = cipher.update(ibuff, 0, r, obuff);
        destination.write(obuff, 0, r);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any code where you close the streams...

Comment: They are closed. See this -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: try with resources, see it now, sorry.

Comment: It definitely has something to do with buffer handling in `processCryptedData`, I don't see it though. Adding a buffer to receive the decrypted data makes it work.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you, but still I'm confused why is that the case since in documentation it's noted update should be copy safe.

Comment: To be fair, that's got me stumped too.

Comment: `update` is copy-safe only of the buffer contains the multiple of the block size. `r = source.read(buff, 0, cipherBlockSize)` is not guaranteed to read the multiple of the block size.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin That's not specifically mentioned in the API as far as I can see, and I do see that cipher implementations contain their own buffer, so there would not be any reason to either. Do you have any source for your claim?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin It is however undoubtedly pointing to the problem, but I've read the documentation over and over and I don't see how you can conclude the behavior out of this; what's probably happening is that the vector (the previous ciphertext block) gets overwritten before it is used.

Comment: Trying to read the Oracle source code, but Cipher -> CipherCore -> CipherBlockChaining. Horrible stuff internally, why can't cryptographers program worth a damn?